# Drop elements from a array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr1 = array(
  'a' => 123,
  'b' => 123,
  'c' => 123,
  'd' => 123,
);

$arr2 = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

How can I remove elements from $arr2 that don't exist as keys in $arr1 ?

for example `e` doesn't exist as key in $arr1 so it should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr2 = array_intersect($arr2, array_keys($arr1))
```

it computes intersection of two sets - `$arr2` values and `$arr1` keys

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ( $arr2 as $key => $value ) {
    if ( !array_key_exists( $value, $arr1 ) ) {
        unset( $arr2[$key] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the simple approach and use `array_keys`? This avoids having to perform an operation for each key by getting ALL of the keys at once.

```
$arr2 = array_keys($arr1);
```

Comment: What if `$arr1` contains elements that are not in `$arr2`?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Then that is a problem. But with the example the OP posted, `array_keys` will work fine.